# android file transfer to wifi printer

Tags: android-layout, android

I want to transfer any office file to a Wi-ifi printer. I have absolutely no idea on how to start with.

Found there are no public APIs for wireless printing.

Could anyone share some inputs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could start by doing a scan for WiFi devices and listing their names and IPs.
Then try filtering them based on their capabilities.

Comment: @user7777777777 how do you filter printer capable devices?

Comment: Guess thats vendor dependent. I just gave you a start.